# JQuery how to set up to make a group of buttons show or hide a group of related elements

Tags: jquery

I have 4 buttons and 4 images. There is a relationship between the buttons and the images so that when button #1 is clicked only div #1 should be visible whilst divs #2, #3 amd #4 are hidden. Same for any other button - show related div and hide the others. This is not specifically related to a menu but I think it is a pattern that would apply there too.

I currently make this work with a jquery on-click function for each button id as below but the code is repetitive.

```
$("#button1").on("click", function(e) {

    $("#div1").show()
    $("#div2").hide()
    $("#div3").hide()
    $("#div4").hide()

})
```

In the future we may add more buttons and divs to the site. So, how can I do this in a more flexible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses the principle of adding classes to elements where the class is not to do with styling but is used as a group identifier:

1. Add a generic class to all the buttons, e.g. myButtonClass
2. Add a generic class to all the divs, e.g. myDivClass
3. Add to each associated div a class matching the controlling button id. e.g.for button #showdiv1 give #div1 an additional class as class="#showdiv1".
4. Now modify your jquery as below:

```js
    $(".myButtonClass").on("click", function(e){
        // hide all the divs
        $(".myDivClass").hide()  
        // show the div with class matching button element id attr
        $("." + $(this).prop("id")).show()    
    })
```

```css
.myDivClass
{
  display: none;
 }

<!-- the following classes are for illustration only -->
.showDiv1 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;}
.showDiv2 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lime;}
.showDiv3 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: gold;}
.showDiv4 { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  <button id="showDiv1" class="myButtonClass">Show Div #1</button>
  <button id="showDiv2" class="myButtonClass">Show Div #2</button>
  <button id="showDiv3" class="myButtonClass">Show Div #3</button>
  <button id="showDiv4" class="myButtonClass">Show Div #4</button>
</div> 

<div id="div1" class="showDiv1 myDivClass">This is Div # 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="showDiv2 myDivClass">This is Div # 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="showDiv3 myDivClass">This is Div # 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="showDiv4 myDivClass">This is Div # 4</div>
```